# What would be an example of the function working with an array of arrays with some logic?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, sub-array

I have a function that takes two arguments, e.g.,

```
function test(a, b) {
if (a == b) return true;
return false;
};
```

What I want is to have a function `func(arg)` that returns `false` by default. It takes one argument, and this argument will be an array of arrays. Each instance of the function will be started with some dynamically generated number (integer), let's call it `myNumber` and let's say it's just some random integer from 0 to 10. This function should do the following:

```
var myNumber = randomIntegerFrom0To10;
var tmp = 0;  
test(arg[0][0], arg[1][0]);
test(arg[0][0], arg[1][1]);
test(arg[0][0], arg[1][2]);
...
```

and as soon as `test(...)` returns `true`, set `tmp++` and go to

```
test(arg[0][1], arg[1][0]);
test(arg[0][1], arg[1][1]);
test(arg[0][1], arg[1][2]);
....
```

and as soon as `test(...)` returns `true`, set `tmp++` and go to

```
test(arg[0][2], arg[1][0]);
test(arg[0][2], arg[1][1]);
test(arg[0][2], arg[1][2]);
...
```

...and so on, until

```
test(arg[0][arg[0].length-1], arg[1][0]);
test(arg[0][arg[0].length-1], arg[1][1]);
test(arg[0][arg[0].length-1], arg[1][2]);
...
```

— as always, as soon as `test(...)` returns `true`, set `tmp++`, but after `test(arg[0][arg[0].length-1], arg[1][arg[1].length-1])`, we must check if `tmp` is equal to `myNumber`. If yes, the function should return `true` and stop; but if not, we must continue (note that we always set `tmp = 0` after each comparison with `myNumber`):

```
tmp = 0;
test(arg[0][0], arg[2][0]);
test(arg[0][0], arg[2][1]);
test(arg[0][0], arg[2][2]);
...
```

and as soon as `test(...)` returns `true`, set `tmp++` ... and so on. If we never see that `tmp` equals to `myNumber`, we will eventually come to

```
test(arg[0][0], arg[arg.length-1][0]);
test(arg[0][0], arg[arg.length-1][1]);
test(arg[0][0], arg[arg.length-1][2]);
```

continuing the logic described above. The longest way here will be to go to

```
test(arg[0][(arg[0].length-1)], arg[arg.length-1][(arg[arg.length-1].length-1)]);
```

and to check the current `tmp`. If it equals to `myNumber`, the function should return `true` and stop, but if not, we must continue:

```
tmp = 0;
test(arg[1][0], arg[2][0]);
test(arg[1][0], arg[2][1]);
test(arg[1][0], arg[2][2]);
...
```

...continue until

```
test(arg[1][(arg[1].length-1)], arg[arg.length-1][(arg[arg.length-1].length-1)]);
```

and check the current `tmp`. As always, either return `true` or continue:

```
tmp = 0;
test(arg[2][0], arg[2][0]);
test(arg[2][0], arg[2][1]);
test(arg[2][0], arg[2][2]);
```

...and so on. The longest theoretically possible way will be to go to

```
test(arg[arg.length-2][(arg[arg.length-2].length-1)], 
arg[arg.length-1][(arg[arg.length-1].length-1)]);
```

and, if current `tmp` equals to `myNumber`, return `true`. Otherwise, return `false` and finally stop.

Example:

```
var myNumber = 1;
var tmp = 0;
var input1 = [ [ 4, 5 ],
          [ 3, 2, 8, 7, 1, 10 ],
          [ 9, 4, 8, 50 ],
          [ 10, 20, 30] 
        ];

// 4 !== 3; tmp == 0;
// 4 !== 2; tmp == 0;
// 4 !== 8; tmp == 0;           
// ...4 !== 10 ; tmp == 0;
// 5 !== 3 ; tmp == 0;
// 5 !== 2 ; tmp == 0;
// ...5 !== 10 ; tmp == 0; is the current tmp equal to myNumber? No. So, continue:
// 3 !== 9 ; tmp == 0;
// 3 !== 4 ; tmp == 0;
// 3 !== 8 ; tmp == 0;
// 3 !== 50 ; tmp == 0;
// 2 !== 9 ; tmp == 0;
// ...2 !== 50 ; tmp == 0;
// 8 !== 9 ; tmp == 0;
// 8 !== 4 ; tmp == 0;
// test(8,8) returns true; set tmp++ and, since there is no need for test(8,50), go to
// 7 !== 9 ; tmp == 1;
// ...7 !== 50 ; tmp == 1;
// 1 !== 9 ; tmp == 1;
// ...10 !== 50; tmp == 1; is the current tmp equal to myNumber? Yes.
// So, return true and stop.
```

If we had the input like this:

```
var input2 = [ [ 1, 2 ],
          [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ],
          [ 9, 10, 11, 12 ],
          [ 13, 14, 15] 
        ];
```

then we would have to perform the maximum possible amount of "test" operations and return `false` after `test(12,15`).
The question is: what would be an example of any working function, such that, following the above logic, will do the actions described for the two given examples of inputs: `func(input1)` and `func(input2)`?

Comment: What is your question? By the way, `if (a == b) return true; return false;` is exactly equivalent to writing `return a == b;`.

Comment: Edited the question and its title, added the question itself. I just need any example of such function, that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a logic of combining rest of the arrays into a single array to compare, that also reduce the logic i need to write.

```
function traverseForMyNumber(){
  var myNumber = 1;
  var tmp = 0;
  var input = [ [ 4, 5 ],
      [ 3, 2, 8, 7, 1, 10 ],
      [ 9, 4, 8, 50 ],
      [ 10, 20, 30] 
    ];
 for(var i = 0; i< input.length; i++){
   var copyArray = input.slice();
   var tempArray  = copyArray.splice(i, 1);

   //Concat rest of the arrays into single arary for easy traversal
   copyArray = [].concat.apply([], copyArray);

   //Logic for incrementing tmp
   for(var j = 0; j< tempArray[0].length; j++){
     for(var k = 0; k < copyArray.length; k++){
       if(test(tempArray[0][j],copyArray[k])){
         tmp++;
         if(tmp === myNumber) return true;
       }
     }
   }
 }
}

function test(a, b) {
  return a === b;
}

traverseForMyNumber();
```